# Text remaining indented after indented block when using insertHtml in QTextEdit

Tags: html, pyqt5, qtextedit

I am making a GUI that has a window with a QTextEdit widget that I am using as a log to track the status of a process running on a separate thread. I have been using HTML to try to control the color and formatting of the text sent to the log but have been running into a number of issues, most of which I have found work-arounds, but I have yet to find information on this on SO or Google.

Every message that is sent to the log is timestamped and wrapped with the `<p>` HTML tag. Since I have a few error messages that print across multiple lines, I have been trying to indent the secondary lines. When I do this, however, every message that is printed after that is also indented, even if I specifically set a 0px indent with the HTML style tag.

I've put together a minimum reproducible example of what I currently have here:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QTextEdit,
    )


class MainWindow(QTextEdit):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: #1E1F22;")
        self.setReadOnly(True)
        self.setLineWrapMode(QTextEdit.NoWrap)

        self.send_to_log()

    def send_to_log(self):
        # Emulate a standard message
        timestamp = f"23:59:59 | "
        text = f"<p style='color: #e5e5e5;'>{timestamp}sample_file1.csv</p>"
        self.insertHtml(text)
        self.append("")
        # ^ Only way I've found to get QTextEdit to print each message to a new line without having a massive amount of
        # whitespace between messages

        # Emulate an error message
        timestamp = f"23:59:59 | "
        text = f"<p style='color: #F75464;'>{timestamp}"
        text += f"<b>FittingError:</b> curve_fit failed while processing:</p>"
        text += f"<p style='color: #F75464; text-indent: 65px'>sample_file1.csv</p>"
        text += (f"<p style='color: #F75464; text-indent: 65px'><b>RuntimeError:</b> "
             f"Optimal parameters not found: Number of calls to function has reached maxfev = 800</p>")
        self.insertHtml(text)
        self.append("")

        # Emulate a standard message
        for i in [2, 3]:
            timestamp = f"23:59:59 | "
            text = f"<p style='color: #e5e5e5; text-indent: 0px'>{timestamp}sample_file{i}.csv</p>"
            self.insertHtml(text)
            self.append("")


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
app.exec()
```

This is what I get after running the code:
[image: MRE output]

I was hoping that `23:59:59 | sample_file2` and subsequent lines would no longer be indented, resuming the normal formatting, but it seems as though the indent from the previous message is persisting somehow.

I would expect to be able to manually set the text-indent property back to 0, or 1px, but neither work.

Additional things I've tried:

- `<pre>` tag and space characters → The plain `<pre>` tag is a block-level element, so it creates an unwanted line-break
- `<pre style='display: inline;'>` → I'm not sure Qt supports the display property for `<pre>` tags
- Changing `text-indent` to `margin-left` (e.g. `<p style='margin-left: 0px;'`) → `margin-left` seems to lead to the same issue as `text-indent`
- `<code>` tag → collapses whitespace
- Formatting everything using HTML tables, putting each line into its own `<tr>` instead of using `<p>` → leaving the first entry of the second and third rows of the table blank didn't preserve the column width even if explicitly defined

I'm relatively new to HTML and PyQt, so I might be missing something obvious, but I have been looking for a solution for a couple days now without finding anything as of yet, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: I should note that this is using PyQt v5.15.10

Comment: @CarlHR It actually is the expected behavior, based on the documentation; maybe not the *preferred* one (and not as documented as it probably could be), but that's a different story. Any insertion at the current cursor position starting with a new paragraph tag (`<p>`) is normally considered as a *continuation* of the current paragraph, and even new lines (considered as simple line breaks, such as `<br>` for HTML or `\n` for text) are still in the current QTextBlock, so they always inherit the current QTextBlockFormat. See my answer for the explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Qt rich text management

A few important aspects to consider about Qt text widgets that provide functions such as `setHtml()`, `toHtml()` and `insertHtml()` (including QLabel's `setText()` that *guesses* if the given string may use HTML tags):

- they are not real *web browsers*;
- they do *not* use the given HTML as it is, but parse it and attempt to convert it in a [QTextDocument](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextdocument.html) structure that only provides *limited* ["rich text" capabilities](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/richtext.html): font, background/foreground colors, tables, *static* images and *basic* layout/alignment features; the implementation is similar to old browsers developed before year 2000, basic text editors like [Microsoft Write](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Write) or [WordPad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordPad), and elementary rich text formats like [`RTF`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format); note that while this may look as a limitation, it's intentionally by design: the purpose is not to have a full web "experience", but to allow basic formatting capabilities while providing reasonable performance (consider the CPU/memory overhead of using a full modern web capable browser renderer just to display something as simple as a red underlined text in a label, and then needing dozens of such labels);
- all this is achieved through a [**small** HTML subset](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/richtext-html-subset.html), which provides *part* of stylesheets features compliant to the CSS 2.1 implementation;
- many html tags and style sheets are possibly reinterpreted to suit (and optimize) the internal structure of the document and/or its capabilities, which might not follow the above HTML standards completely;
- the given HTML is **never** stored: `toHtml()` will *always* return a quite different output than what used for `setHtml()`; the only exception is QLabel, which will always return the `text()` used for `setText()`, even if it's interpreted as HTML;
- QTextDocument uses [QTextFormat](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextformat.html) subclasses to define hierarchical characteristics of each element: for instance, QTextBlockFormat defines aspects of a paragraph (including alignment or indentation) similarly to what `<p>` does, QTextCharFormat specifies more defined features of each *fragment* of text in a block (paragraph), like what tags such as `<span>` or `<b>` do;

Finally, QTextDocument uses the [QTextCursor interface](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/richtext-cursor.html) for editing, always inserting new content with the current text format, which is the format of the character at the left of the current cursor position (or the right if at the beginning of a document). When using `insertHtml()` it also *assumes* that the inserted html is just a continuation of the previous content, meaning that appending a HTML starting with a paragraph (`<p>`) will just *merge* it with the previous format ignoring the new paragraph.

This may seem unintuitive, but the reason comes from the fact that `insertHtml()` is actually used when doing clipboard operations: when copying rich text, the clipboard actually contains a fully compliant HTML document (even if you just copied one letter) and when pasting that content Qt has no way to know if the insertion is to be considered as coming from the clipboard or not.
Interestingly enough, that's exactly what most rich text editors in web browsers do: even when you select and copy a full paragraph with custom "block" aspects (such as indentation), when it's pasted in an existing paragraph, those aspects will be ignored, and the current one will be preserved instead.

### Possible solutions

Now, there are many ways to achieve what you want.

The simplest solution is to always add new HTML starting with a line break (`<br>`). With this, you could even just use `<span>`, and that's because `text-indent` (following the HTML standard) actually applies the indentation only to the first line of the paragraph.

Another alternative is to always insert a new block with a default QTextBlockFormat before adding a new paragraph. To do so, you need to access the QTextCursor of the document, then you can use its own `insertHtml()` directly (which is what QTextEdit and therefore QTextDocument actually do):

```py
    tc = self.textCursor()
    ...
    tc.insertBlock(QTextBlockFormat())
    tc.insertHtml(text)
    ...
```

In case you want to avoid the insertion of an empty line at the beginning while the contents are still empty, just check the current cursor position:

```py
    tc.movePosition(tc.End) # 1
    if (
        tc.position() # 2
        and not tc.atBlockStart() # a
        or tc.blockFormat().textIndent() # b
    ):
        tc.insertBlock(QTextBlockFormat()) # 3
    tc.insertHtml(text)
    ...
```

What the above does is:

1. move cursor to the end of the document (necessary in case the user has clicked on the editor, possibly to select some text);
2. check if some content already exists; *and* if it does:

   a. ensure that it's not at the beginning of a block/paragraph;

   b. alternatively, verify if the current block format has indentation set by the `text-indent` CSS;
3. eventually insert a new block/paragraph;

### Final considerations

While the HTML features Qt provides may be sometimes helpful and simpler, they often presents some important drawbacks similar to those you're facing.

One possibility is to properly set the [`defaultStyleSheet()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextdocument.html#defaultStyleSheet-prop) on the document and also use HTML classes, but some proper digging into the documentation could actually simplify all the above (and would certainly be helpful in your experience).

Consider the following:

```py
class MainWindow(QTextEdit):
    def __init__(self):
        ...
        doc = self.document()
        doc.setIndentWidth(65)

        self.standard_format = QTextBlockFormat()
        self.standard_format.setForeground(QColor('#e5e5e5'))
        self.error_format = QTextBlockFormat()
        self.error_format.setForeground(QColor('#f75464'))
        self.error_format.setIndent(1)
        self.error_format.setTextIndent(-65)
        self.send_to_log()

    def add_content(self, content, format):
        tc = self.textCursor()
        tc.movePosition(tc.End)
        if (
            tc.position()
            and not tc.atBlockStart()
            or tc.blockFormat().textIndent()
        ):
            tc.insertBlock(format)

        pos = tc.position()
        tc.insertHtml(content)
        tc.setPosition(pos, tc.KeepAnchor)
        if tc.blockFormat() != format:
            tc.setBlockFormat(format)
        tc.setCharFormat(format.toCharFormat())

    def add_standard_message(self, timestamp, message):
        self.add_content(
            '{} | {}'.format(timestamp, message), 
            self.standard_format
        )

    def add_error_message(self, timestamp, err_contents):
        self.add_content(
            '{} | {}'.format(timestamp, '<br>'.join(err_contents)), 
            self.error_format
        )

    def send_to_log(self):
        timestamp = "23:59:59"
        self.add_standard_message(timestamp, 'sample_file1.csv')
        err_contents = (
            '<b>FittingError:</b> curve_fit failed while processing', 
            'sample_file1.csv', 
            '<b>RuntimeError</b> Optimal parameters not found: Number of '
                'calls to function has reached maxfev = 800'
        )
        self.add_error_message(timestamp, err_contents)

        for i in (2, 3):
            self.add_standard_message(
                timestamp, 'sample_file{}.csv'.format(i))
```

Finally, and completely unrelated but still quite important, you shall **never** set generic QSS (Qt Style Sheet) properties on complex widgets as you did with `self.setStyleSheet("background-color: #1E1F22;")`, as they will propagate to *all* child widgets, including complex widgets that require full definition of their properties whenever *any* property is set (like scroll bars). If you want to set the background of the QTextEdit, the only valid and acceptable way to do so is by using proper [selectors](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html#selector-types); for instance, in your case:

```py
    self.setStyleSheet("MainWindow { background-color: #1E1F22; }")
```

<sup>The above assumes that, based on your code, `MainWindow` is the target of the QSS, and using a `QTextEdit` selector would also work, since `MainWindow` inherits from it; obviously, if `MainWindow` *contains* the QTextEdit, you may need a different selector that actually targets that widget or its class(es).</sup>

Comment: Wow, this clarifies a whole lot. Thank you for taking the time to give such a detailed answer!

As for the QSS on the QTextEdit, duly noted. I've only really started learning Qt about a month ago, at this point, so I appreciate the tip.

Comment: @dustin_dawind You're very welcome. Keep in mind that the whole QTextDocument API is quite complex (as text layout management is in general), and while the documentation is normally extensive as with most Qt docs, getting the full grasp of how it all works and how each class interacts with the others requires a lot of patience and experiments in order to understand all of it (or, at least, begin to...). You shouldn't be afraid to dig into all those docs, and you probably aren't, but... "You will be... You will be." [cit.]  ;-)